# Statically or dynamically linking to C-Runtime (CRT) for binaries running in containers?

Tags: c++, docker, static-linking, crt

So far, I've always preferred statically linking to CRT for its advantages. Does the fact that I'm going to run the binaries in containers make any difference? I'm new to Docker and I'd like to know if there's the "right" way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no right way in Docker about linking your executable. You can continue linking your libraries statically.

In fact `Docker` may be useful for testing your application in different environments, to see whether you have anticipated all necessary dependencies. In this case, when you are performing **static** link, Docker will add nothing, but with dynamic you will be able to watch the behavior of your code in different environment, like `glibc/musl` in Linux or whatever.

We've made a great use of Docker in testing out application on different versions of `boost`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'll accept the answer if no one comes up with a better one. BTW, the environment is also mine, but I'd like to not care when it changes.